# Copy Data to Spark Environment

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr, sparklyr, azure-databricks

I am trying to copy my data into spark and getting the following error

Error in as.data.frame.default(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, row.names = FALSE,  : 
  cannot coerce class "structure("SparkDataFrame", package = "SparkR")" to a data.frame

I've looked over the documentation and found nothing that helps

```
library(SparkR)
DF <- read.df("/FileStore/tables/export.csv", source = "csv", header="true", inferSchema = "true")

library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
sc <- spark_connect(method = "databricks")
#This gives the above error
DF_tbl <- sdf_copy_to(sc = sc, x = DF, overwrite = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this without access to `export.csv`, but the problem may arise from mixing a [SparkR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SparkR/vignettes/sparkr-vignettes.html) function (*ie*, `read.df()`) with [sparklyr](https://spark.rstudio.com/) functions (*ie*, `spark_connect()` and `sdf_copy_to()`).

I'm guessing that `sparklyr::sdf_copy_to()` doesn't accept an object of SparkR's 'SparkDataFrame' class.

Try replacing `SparkR::read.df()` with something like `readr::read_csv()` or `data.table::fread()`.